# Get Radio Button Value into another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my radio buttons' code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 alert alert-success" dir="rtl" >
    Select an Option <br>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="sp" id="sp1" value="1" checked>
            <span style="margin-right: 30px;">Option-1</span>
    </label><br>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="sp" id="sp2" value="2">
            <span style="margin-right: 30px;">Option-2</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

and I want to get value of button in following script audio src, so by clicking on radio button I can switch between media folder:

```
function PlayVerse(surat,n) {
     var aud=document.getElementById("myaudio");
     aud.src= "http://data.quranacademy.com/AUDIOS/Media-/01_"
               +TxtFormat(surat,"000")
               +"_"
               +TxtFormat(n,"000")
               +".mp3";
}

var x = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style = 'display: inline-block; '
                 +'border: 1px solid #ddd; '
                 +'border-radius: 4px; padding: 5px;';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Arif Shahid. Your question does not show evidence of any attempts that you have made. What have you tried that did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this with plain javascript

```js
function PlayVerse(){
var radio = document.getElementsByName('sp');
var check;
for (var i = 0, length = radio.length; i < length; i++)
{
 if (radio[i].checked)
 {
  console.log(radio[i].value);
   check = radio[i].value;
  break;
 }
}
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 alert alert-success" dir="rtl" >Select an Option</br>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="sp" id="sp1" value="1" checked><span style="margin-right: 30px;">Option-1
</span></label></br>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="sp" id="sp2" value="2"><span style="margin-right: 30px;">Pption-2
</span></label>
</div>
<button type = "button" onclick="PlayVerse();">Get Radio button value  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get value of `radio button` which one is checked. Get all `NodeList` by [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) and iterate over each one and check if it is checked.

```js
function getVal(elementName) {
 var radios = document.getElementsByName(elementName), rValue = null;
 for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  if (radios[i].checked) {
   rValue = radios[i].value;
   break;
  }
 }
  console.log(rValue);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 alert alert-success" dir="rtl" >
    Select an Option <br>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" onchange="getVal('sp')" name="sp" id="sp1" value="1" checked>
            <span style="margin-right: 30px;">Option-1</span>
    </label><br>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" onchange="getVal('sp')" name="sp" id="sp2" value="2">
            <span style="margin-right: 30px;">Option-2</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do something by clicking on `radio button` it can help you

```
window.onload=function(){

    (function (){
      var radios = document.getElementsByName('sp');
      radios.forEach(function(radio){
        radio.onclick = function(){
              alert(this.value);
              //do something
          }
      })
    })();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Red color
    Yelow color

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        //var x = document.getElementById("myRadioRed").value;
        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('colors');

        for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].checked) {
                // do whatever you want with the checked radio
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = radios[i].value;

                // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
                break;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" id="myRadioRed" onchange="myFunction()" checked="checked" />Red color
    <input type="radio" name="colors" value="yellow" id="myRadioYellow" onchange="myFunction()" />Yelow color

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function PlayVerse() {
   var selected_radio_button_value = getRadioButtonValue("sp");
   alert(selected_radio_button_value);
   }
   
 function getRadioButtonValue(elementName) {
    var array1 = document.getElementsByName(elementName), rValue = null;
    array1.forEach(function(element) {
      if( element.checked ) {
        rValue = element.value;
        return true;
      }
    });
    return rValue;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 alert alert-success" dir="rtl" >Select an Option</br>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="sp" id="sp1" value="1" checked><span style="margin-right: 30px;">Option-1
</span></label></br>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="sp" id="sp2" value="2"><span style="margin-right: 30px;">Pption-2
</span></label>
</div>
<button type = "button" onclick="PlayVerse();">Get Radio button value  </button>
```

here you can get value of radio button using javascript i have created an function which will give you value of selected radio button you can store that value in variable and access it anywhere you want  you can do it in both way